# Blob counter in javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing

Is there any library in pure javascript for counting blobs in an image ? Like the one from AForge.NET . i don't really need anything complete . just a simple way to detect a blob and getting its location . 
This is the image i have after filtering irrelevant colors:

[image]

Also this is how i filtered the image :

```
if (imgData.data[i] > 252) {
    imgData.data[i] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
} else {
    imgData.data[i] = 255;
    imgData.data[i + 1] = 255;
    imgData.data[i + 2] = 255;
    imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
}
```

This is done for every pixel . ( basically i kept anything with red >252 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though i found a library in javascript i decided to write exactly what i needed . I just published it in github :

https://github.com/amirhkkh/blobcounter.js

But it's still very odd that there isn't much interest into this subject .